# Secure page admin Solr

Tags: solr

Installed Solr5.3.0 on Windows and imported data. Can somebody guide me how to secure mydomain/ip:8983/solr from public.

I want to secure all page of solr except the query & select. I want keep them publically.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/query?
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?
```

This  my config example/etc/webdefault.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>core1-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

Comment: Use a more recent version of Solr that supports authentication and authorization natively? There are more than one way to work around assuming those two urls are read only.

Comment: MatsLindh: There are more than one way to work around assuming those two urls are read only
Can you tell me one way ?

Comment: Look at the `qt` parameter, which allows you to override the selected query handler depending on configuration.